# I need to find the difference in years between today and a list of dates

Tags: python, list, datetime

I am trying to write a simple function to compare a list of dates to today in order to find dates that are more than 13 years old. For the first part of the challenge I’m just trying to write the function that will compare the dates to find the difference today and each in the birthdays list.

```
import datetime

birthdays = [
    datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 29),
    datetime.datetime(2006, 8, 9),
    datetime.datetime(1978, 5, 16),
    datetime.datetime(1981, 8, 15),
    datetime.datetime(2001, 7, 4),
    datetime.datetime(1999, 12, 30)
]

today = datetime.datetime.today()


def is_over_13(dt):
    Diff = (today - dt)
    Return (diff)

Is_over_13(birthdays)
```

The problem I seem to be facing is that I’m trying to compare a datetime object to a list. So my thinking is that I need to be able to do something to the list to make it compatible to compare? Or the other way round.

I’m learning Python and this is step 1 of a specific code challenge so I can’t use lambda or panda or libraries. I’m expected to do it using functional chaining or comprehensions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just loop over the list and pass each list item into your function? You should also consider that your function does not return whether a date occurs more than 13 years in the past, but rather would return the difference between the two dates (potential syntax issues aside).

Comment: `[b for b in birthdays if (today - b).days / 365.2425 > 13]`

Comment: @esqew - thank you. I realised that I was only returning the difference and that there was another step needed. I ended up setting the difference as diff = today - dt, then I added return (diff.days >= 4745). When I then called the function using the ‘birthdays’ list, it worked and passed the challenge. Thanks again.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp - this was much more like the answer I started trying to write, but I just couldn’t quite figure how to write the math bit and I think I wasn’t calling the .day attribute. Thank again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few tweaks to makes.

```
import datetime

birthdays = [
    datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 29),
    datetime.datetime(2006, 8, 9),
    datetime.datetime(1978, 5, 16),
    datetime.datetime(1981, 8, 15),
    datetime.datetime(2001, 7, 4),
    datetime.datetime(1999, 12, 30)
]

today = datetime.datetime.today()


def is_over_13(dt):
    diff = (today - dt) # you have capital D, need to match variable name with lower case.
    return diff  # Return should be return
    
for birthday in birthdays:  # loop over each day to check
    print(is_over_13(birthday))  ## you have capital I, needs to match your function name with lower case i
```

Also your function name says is_over_13 which implies true or false return i think.  You might want to take the `diff` value and compare it to 13 years and return true or false

This might look like

```
import datetime

birthdays = [
    datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 29),
    datetime.datetime(2006, 8, 9),
    datetime.datetime(1978, 5, 16),
    datetime.datetime(1981, 8, 15),
    datetime.datetime(2001, 7, 4),
    datetime.datetime(1999, 12, 30)
]

today = datetime.datetime.today()
DAYS_IN_YEAR = 365
YEARS = 13

def is_over_13(dt):
    diff = (today - dt).days # get the days for your diff
    return diff > (DAYS_IN_YEAR * YEARS)  # return if greater than 13 or not

for birthday in birthdays:  
    print(is_over_13(birthday))
```

Comment: My bad, I am just starting to use an iPad and hadn’t worked out how to stop capitalisation at the start of a sentence, hence the big D. Your answer is pretty much what I did. diff.days >= 4745. Thanks @Josh Adams

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started. You need a loop. In this case, I used a comprehension:

```
import datetime

birthdays = [
    datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 29),
    datetime.datetime(2006, 8, 9),
    datetime.datetime(1978, 5, 16),
    datetime.datetime(1981, 8, 15),
    datetime.datetime(2001, 7, 4),
    datetime.datetime(1999, 12, 30)
]

today = datetime.datetime.today()

>>> [f'{today.date()} - {bd.date()}>13: {((today-bd).days)>365.2425*13}' for bd in birthdays]
['2022-01-05 - 2012-04-29>13: False', '2022-01-05 - 2006-08-09>13: True', '2022-01-05 - 1978-05-16>13: True', '2022-01-05 - 1981-08-15>13: True', '2022-01-05 - 2001-07-04>13: True', '2022-01-05 - 1999-12-30>13: True']
```

Because of leap years, time differences are expressed in days, minutes, seconds. This uses a common, but less than perfect, shortcut of estimating a year difference by multiplying a day difference by 365.2425 that is *usually* accurate but not 100%.

To get 100% accuracy, you need to detect leap year birthdays and adjust the date to `2/28/the_year` in a non-leap year.

To do that, use this function:

```
def is_older_than(bd, age, day=datetime.datetime.today()):
    try:
        age_date=bd.replace(year=bd.year+age)
    except ValueError:
        age_date=bd.replace(year=bd.year+age, day=28)
        
    return age_date<=day
```

Then redo the loop that will be accurate by the day no matter what:

```
>>> [f'{today.date()} - {bd.date()}>13: {is_older_than(bd, 13)}' for bd in birthdays]
['2022-01-05 - 2012-04-29>13: False', '2022-01-05 - 2006-08-09>13: True', '2022-01-05 - 1978-05-16>13: True', '2022-01-05 - 1981-08-15>13: True', '2022-01-05 - 2001-07-04>13: True', '2022-01-05 - 1999-12-30>13: True']
```

Comment: Thank you @dawg. I should have explained that the challenge asked me to ignore leap years, my bad. I much prefer the idea of a comprehension approach, less code and all that. Your answer is a little over my head given my current level of progress, but I think I get the jist. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a loop.

```
for dt in birthdays:
    diff=(today-dt)
return diff
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks @Sanchez. The only bit you’ve not covered in your answer is how to then compare the dates to see if they are more than 13yrs old. Some of the above answers show this. However, indeed I did need a loop. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over a list of datetimes to all compare them one by one with today.
This function will return True if one date is over 13 years.

```
def is_it_over_13(birthday_list):
    for date in birthday_list:
        if abs(today - date) > datetime.timedelta(days = 13*365):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Not come across abs() before. Is this some sort of Absolute type thing?

Comment: yes, the absolute value. Kind of lazy thing there as I know from your example that `date` is always in the past.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

birthdays = [
    datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 29),
    datetime.datetime(2006, 8, 9),
    datetime.datetime(1978, 5, 16),
    datetime.datetime(1981, 8, 15),
    datetime.datetime(2001, 7, 4),
    datetime.datetime(1999, 12, 30)
]

def is_over_13(dt):
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    diff = (datetime.datetime.now() - dt).days
    # 4745 == 13*365
    if diff>4745:
        return dt

for i in birthdays:
    print(is_over_13(i))
```

Comment: That looks to be pretty much how I did it. Just a question, what made you move the today variable inside the function rather the leaving it outside? :)

Comment: You can put the today variable outside. My intution is only, made a complete function not dependent on outside variable.